# Probability of first and second run of coin tosses

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A coin when flipped shows heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $q = 1 − p$. It is flipped repeatedly. Assume that the outcome of different
flips is independent. Let $X$ be the length of the initial run and $Y$ the length of the second run.

Evaluate $P(X=2)$ and $P(Y=3)$ and $P(X=2\:$ and $\:Y=3)$

Since for the first run of length 2 is either $HHT$ or $TTH$, I have $P(X=2)=p^2q+q^2p\:$, but I'm not sure how to evaluate the second and third part of the question. I'm thinking that the second run is either $...THHHT$ or $...HTTTH$ so $P(Y=3)=q^2p^3+p^2q^3$.

But the notes my lecturer asked us to refer to show that $P(Y=3)=q^2p^{3-1}+p^2q^{3-1}=q^2p^2+p^2q^2$, which I dont understand. The notes also show the probability is derived from an infinite sum, which we are specified NOT to do, but to do it by conditioning on the first toss instead.

Comment: For me it is not clear how $X$ and $Y$ are defined. If $X=3$ you just flip the coin 3 times or what?

Comment: @callculus $X$ is the first run of coin tosses which have the same result. ie. If $X=5$, my tosses will either look like 5 consecutive heads followed by some number of tails or 5 consecutive tails followed by some number of heads

Comment: similarly, Y is the second run of coin tosses, so if $Y=4$, my very first run will be some number of consecutive heads followed by 4 consecutive tails then followed by some number of conscutive heads or vice versa for if the first run was tails

Comment: That´s not easy. I think the exercise can be solved with backwards induction. I´m not an expert in that subject but other users here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the probability of tossing a tail be $q=1-p$

$P(X=2)$ is the probability of tossing $HHT$ or $TTH$, $$\therefore P(X=2)=p^2q+q^2p$$
$P(Y=3)$ is the probability of tossing $H...HTTTH$ or $T...THHHT$. Thus we need to account for all possible values of the first run

$$
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} 
\therefore P(Y=3)&=(p+p^2+p^3+...)(q^3p)+(q+q^2+q^3+...)(p^3q) \\ 
&=p(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} p^n)q^3p+q(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} q^n)p^3q \\
&=p^2q^3\frac{1}{1-p}+q^2p^3\frac{1}{1-q}\\
&=p^2q^2+p^2q^2 \\
&=2p^2q^2
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
$$
$P(X=2\; \text{and} \; Y=3)$is the probability of tossing $HHTTTH$ or $TTHHHT$, 
$$
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\therefore P(X=2\; \text{and} \; Y=3)&=p^2q^3p+q^2p^3q \\
&=2p^3q^3
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the question itself as a coin flip with two trials.

What is the probability my coin is heads once AND heads another time. It will be $$(1/2)^{2} = 0.25. $$

So when the question asks what is the probability X = 2 and Y = 3, the and can be thought of as multiplicative just like the heads a coin toss.

---

What is the probability that our initial run is exactly of length 2 AND the second run is of length 3?

$$((p^{2}*q) + (q^{2}*p))  * ((p^{3}*q) + (q^{3}*p)).$$

In general, it is useful to think of AND as multiplication and OR as addition.

Comment: the question does not specify whether the coin is fair or not. Additionally, for $P(X=2)$, the first 2 tosses need to be heads, followed by a tails or the first 2 tosses need to be tails, followed by a heads

Comment: The answer is generalized assuming that $$  0 \leq p \leq 1$$ and q = 1 - p. It is that in general when you see "and", it is multiplication. 

I guess the coin example with 1/2 was a bit confusing see as your question was a coin toss question.

Comment: so would you have $P(Y=3)=p^3q+q^3p$?

Comment: Your solution for $P(X=2 \; \text {and} \; Y=3)$ is wrong. I've posted the correct solution